# overlaying a video on top of another

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two videos content video and overlay video. overlay video is nothing but video generated from a vector animation and it has a white background. i am able to overlay the animation video on top of content video using overlay filter in ffmpeg. But i want to get rid of white background in my overlay video while overlaying . Is there a way to do what i am trying to do  directly from ffmpeg command line tool ?

Comment: Can you export the video from the animation with a transparent background into some format that supports alpha channels?

Comment: not with the tools i am working with. i am using gnash to dump swf animation to raw rgb video. there are some other tools which can dump swf to other video formats but i wanted to use something that i can control programatically hence gnash.